# How to remove colored label square

Tags: chart.js

I have this red square near the label:

[image]

How to remove this?

This is my chart imoplementation

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(chart').getContext("2d");

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            responsive: true,
            data: {
                labels: ["test"]
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Sfarzoso",
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#000',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    data: ["1"]
                    backgroundColor: ["#fff5f7"]
                }]
            },
        });
```

How can i achieve such result?

Comment: Please show your code in a [mcve]

Comment: @ochi check update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add options object and indicate not to display the legend

```
var options = {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    };
```

Then use the options in the constructor of your chart

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  responsive: true,
  /* include options in the constructor */
  options: options,
  ... }
```

**See sample below**

Documentation about options available are on their website: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext("2d");

// add options object - indicate not to display the legend
var options = {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    };

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  responsive: true,
  /* include options in the constructor */
  options: options,
  data: {
    labels: ["test"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Sfarzoso",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: '#000',
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      data: ["1"],
      backgroundColor: ["#fff5f7"]
    }]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```